# SQL syntax error in excel formula

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a VBA formula that is causing my excel macro to not run.  it gives a syntax error; but no specifics.  can anyone take a look and see what my issue might be?  I would appreciate it.

thank you.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(
RC[-14]=RC[-11],RC[-14]&"" is Head of Household
at ""&IF(RC[-6]="""",RC[-9]&"",
    ""&RC[-8]&"",""&RC[-7],RC[-6]&"",""&RC[-9]&"",""&RC[-8]&"",""&RC[-7]),
IF(RC[-12]=""Cen-Head"",""Head of Household at
 ""&IF(RC[-6]="""",RC[-9]&"",
""&RC[-8]&"",""&RC[-7],RC[-6]&"",
""&RC[-9]&"",""&RC[-8]&"",""&RC[-7]),
""Enumerated with ""
&IF(RC[-6]="""",(RC[-14]&"" at
""&RC[-9]&"",""&RC[-8]&"",""&RC[-7]),
(RC[-14]&"" at ""&RC[-6]&"",""&RC[-9]&"",""&RC[-8]&"",""&RC[-7]))
)"
```

Comment: This formula is a mess and you should think about paring it down (and this is language agnostic advice).

Comment: I'm happy to do that.  do you have any guidance on what that might look like?  would I somehow split it into more than one piece?  I realize it's a long formula.  it's basically an if statement, with another nested if statement inside.

Comment: Can you assign the inner `IF` statement to a separate variable?  This will also make it much easier to debug.

Comment: I'll give that a try.  I guess I could also extract the nested if statement, and get it to work first; but I think that's effectively what you're saying to do.

Comment: Separate each piece and test them individually, then bring them together in one formula if you really want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your title mentions SQL, there is none in your formula.

That aside, I wasn't sure if you ever figured this out, but the issue looks to be a mismatch in parentheses, specifically you need an additional closing paren at the end of the formula.

This formula is fairly messy though so I may have missed something else. That does get to another point though after having spent about 30 minutes trying to clean it up to be more readable I had to throw in the towel. So I would strongly suggest either:

- Moving the IF logic into your macro code and just determine the value there and then hard set it (i.e. set the cell's `.Value` instead of `.Formula`)
- Fill in a working version of the formula in a throw away cell somewhere in your workbook, and then just use copy paste to apply the formula where it's actually needed

Since I don't have any context on what the formula is for and what else the macro is doing I can't tell which would be better in this case. However, either is better than trying to use what you have.

There are a couple things I'll suggest as ways to make setting formulas from VBA cleaner and easier to read though for future use.
1) You have a lot of places where you need a " to appear in the formula. For readability sake I've found it's best to declare a variable and set it to ", like so:

```
Dim dq as string
dq = chr(34) 'chr 34 is the unicode value for "
```

2) Since we're using VBA code to fill in a formula, using `&` in place of using the `CONCATENATE` formula makes things hard to follow (is that a concatenate for the VBA or for the formula?). So you should only use `&` for VBA concatenation and use `CONCATENATE` inside the actual formula string.